# ClusterManager on Android not always working as it should

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I was trying to create a custom marker with Clusters on android maps. So I created the `MarkerCluster` clas and the `ClusterManagerRender` and it does render on the map, the problem is, it's not always that it does. I'm not sure if there's a default value, because right now, besides the current Marker for the user position, there's only two locations on the map, and it's showing only one !

```
public class MarkerCluster implements ClusterItem {
private LatLng position;
private String title;
private String snippet;
private String image;
private Model model;

public MarkerCluster(LatLng position, String title, String snippet, String image, Model model) {
    this.position = position;
    this.title = title;
    this.snippet = snippet;
    this.image = image;
    this.model = model;
}
public MarkerCluster(){}

@Override
public LatLng getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(LatLng position) {
    this.position = position;
}

@Override
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@Override
public String getSnippet() {
    return snippet;
}

public void setSnippet(String snippet) {
    this.snippet = snippet;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public Model getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(Model model) {
    this.model = model;
}
```

The manager :

```
public class ClusterManagerRender extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MarkerCluster> {
private final IconGenerator iconGenerator;
private final ImageView imageView;
private final int markerWidth;
private final int markerHeight;


public ClusterManagerRender(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<MarkerCluster> clusterManager) {
    super(context, map, clusterManager);

    iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(context.getApplicationContext());
    imageView = new ImageView(context.getApplicationContext());
    markerWidth = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_marker_image);
    markerHeight = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_marker_image);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(markerWidth,markerHeight));
    int padding = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_marker_padding);
    imageView.setPadding(padding,padding,padding,padding);
    iconGenerator.setContentView(imageView);

}

@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MarkerCluster item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    Picasso.get().load(item.getImage()).into(imageView);
    Bitmap bitmap = iconGenerator.makeIcon();
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)).title(item.getTitle());
}

@Override
protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<MarkerCluster> cluster) {
    return false;
}
```

And the response from the server :

```
private void DrawPinsOnMap(List<com.corp.barros.brasil.initiallocation.Model> list){
    if(clusterManager == null){
        clusterManager = new ClusterManager<MarkerCluster>(getApplicationContext(),mMap);
    }
    if(clusterManagerRender == null){
        clusterManagerRender = new ClusterManagerRender(getApplicationContext(),mMap,clusterManager);
        clusterManager.setRenderer(clusterManagerRender);
    }

    clusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MarkerCluster>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClusterItemClick(MarkerCluster markerCluster) {
            com.corp.barros.brasil.initiallocation.Model mm = markerCluster.getModel();

            return false;
        }


    });

    for (com.corp.barros.brasil.initiallocation.Model m: list) {
        String ti = null;
        String sn = null;

        if(m.getName() != null){
            ti = m.getName();
        }else {
            ti = "Anônimo";
        }


        MarkerCluster markerCluster = new MarkerCluster(new LatLng(m.getLat(),m.getLong()),ti,m.getTitle(),m.getUrl(),m);
        clusterManager.addItem(markerCluster);
        markerClusters.add(markerCluster);
    }
}
```

Comment: Give more details on the problem. Attach screenshots.

Comment: There isn't! Sometimes all the markers got rendered on the map, and sometimes only one just show even with the ClusterMarkers list been filled with 2 items.

Comment: Try overriding `protected void onClusterItemRendered(T clusterItem, Marker marker)` in `ClusterManagerRender` and log marker info.  Should be called with each/all map markers given `shouldRenderAsCluster` is always false.